# Is initializing variables in a namespace similar to initializing them as a class member?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

In other words: is it fair to say that a namespace has member variables and functions just like a class does?

Comment: Not really, because you can't have instances of a namespace.

Comment: Not really.   All members of a class are (syntactically at least) within a namespace with the same name as the class, but variables and functions in a namespace are not necessarily in any class.  A namespace also cannot be constructed or destructed.

Comment: Thanks @QuantumPete ! I'm not sure why I've got downvoted but thank you for taking time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The terms member, member variables, member functions and methods are commonly used for class (struct) variables and functions only.

Functions in a namespace are just functions in the scope of the namespace, like variables are simply variables in the scope of the namespace.

Besides the differences between namespaces and classes regarding access and other stuff, the most import difference here is that you can create multiple objects of a class which then each hold their data in their member variables, and the methods == member functions work on this data.

Comment: Thank you! That clears things up for me! I'm not sure why I've got downvoted but thank you for taking time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. A `namespace` is used to limit the scope of variables, functions and classes. Meaning that by putting them into a namespace, you can have the same named function appear in your code and distinguish them through the use of a namespace.

A class is meant to represent a self-contained set of data (the variables) with a set of operations (the functions) to be performed on that data.

While you can have classes that only have static members and only publicly accessible variables, you start to lose the advantages (and the point) of classes.

Comment: More generally, a namespace limits the scope of **names** (other than preprocessor macros, of course). "Variables, functions, and classes" covers many of the names that are commonly used, but doesn't address all of them; typedef names and templates come immediately to mind. +1.